# jquery hover not called on elements that get the class after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have an ip validation for my MVC based website that does the "crude"  frontend validation of an IPv4 field. If the ip get's changed it will add an image and an error message to this field.

However, this seems to only work for data that comes from the back-end.
Fields with incorrect data coming from the backend and thus loaded before my Javascript loads. have a "hover"  event. fields that get the validation-invalid class after loading do not have the hover event.

How do i go about fixing this? i've tried on mouseenter, mouseleave aswell.

```
$(".validation-invalid").hover(function () {
    $("#" + $(this)[0].id + "-error").toggle();
});

function validateIPv4(sender) {
    var ip = $(sender).val();
    var ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;

    if (ip.match(ipformat)) {
            $(sender).removeClass("validation-invalid").addClass("validation-valid");
    } else {
        $(sender).addClass("validation-invalid").removeClass("validation-valid");
        $('<span class="error-popover" id="' + $(sender)[0].id + '-error"><img class="error-callout" src="/Content/images/callout.png" alt="Help pointer">@GlobalizedResources.Device_Configuration_Page_IPv4_Error</span>').insertAfter(sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: change `hover` to `on('hover',`

Comment: You will have to use something called _event delegation_ in JQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically the events are bound when the elements are present in DOM, so to attach events to dynamically generated elements jQuery provides other APIs to do this. Old jQuery version provides [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind) and new version provides [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) APIs.

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".validation-invalid", function () {
    $("#" + $(this)[0].id + "-error").toggle();
});

//Instead of "document" use the wrapper/container of ".validation-invalid"
```

Comment: ohh. right..`mouseover` needs to be added.. almost forgot while copy pasting OP's code

Comment: And `mouseout` aswell : `$(document).on("mouseover mouseout", ".validation-invalid", function () {`

Comment: So Karl-Andre your solution works but i have to click everytime to make this work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon why `mouseout`.. I am not using `mouseenter` and as per jQuery `.on( "mouseover", handler )` is available

Comment: @vinayakj because op is using `hover`, which is a shortcut of [`mouseenter mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2). That mean it should actually be `$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".validation-invalid", function () {`

Comment: @Puzzle84 try `$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".validation-invalid", function () {`

Comment: OP havent mentioned explicitely whether he wants to trigger the event on inner elements so we can use `mouseover`. Also previously you commented `$(document).on("mouseover mouseout", ".validation-invalid", function () { ` not `mouseenter mouseleave.`

Comment: Yes, I commented `mouseout mouseover`, but I was mistaken. It is really `mouseenter mouseleave `. You need to use both since OP use `.toggle()` in the function. That mean when the mouse leave the element, the error should disappear, which will not happen if you leave only `mouseenter`. Only using `mouseentre` will make the error toggle only when the mouse enter the element.

Comment: I think OP could answer better which one fits it better for OP, only If replies back here. Anyways thanks for pointing out `.on('hover'`

Comment: Karl has the answer with $(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".validation-invalid", function () { If you want to post an answer. i'll mark it as The Answer.